# Round up to the nearest whole even number

Tags: algorithm, excel, vba

I think a simple maths question, I'm looking for an algorithm to round up to the nearest whole even number so

```
4.4 = 6
5.1 = 6
2.1 = 4
1.9 = 2 etc....
```

If you could give me the VBA syntax that would be awesome. 
I know excel as `=even(..)` function but I can't get it to work in VBA.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Le_Morri, no. I am looking for the nearest _even_ number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the Excel function using:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Even(YourNumber)
```

Comment: + 1 You beat me to it.